# Apache/Server Logs help

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files, centos5, windows-event-log

I have this on my apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin info@myweb.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
ServerName web.myweb.com
ErrorLog logs/index-error_log
CustomLog logs/index-access_log common 
</VirtualHost>
```

And now I have 500 error but I can't find any index-error-log and /etc/httpd/logs/error_log didn't show anything...

Can someone help me locate the logs so I can see what causing the 500 error.

Thanks

note: myweb.com is not my real web just for example

Here is my latest log (show nothing about the error)

```
[Mon Sep 26 01:52:37 2011] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 26 01:53:13 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Sep 26 01:53:13 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Sep 26 01:53:13 2011] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Sep 26 01:53:13 2011] [notice] Digest: done
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mcrypt' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[Mon Sep 26 01:53:13 2011] [notice] Apache configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the error log for virtual host is created in `/etc/httpd/logs` which is a symlink to `/var/log/httpd`. As a temporary, you can comment the `ErrorLog` directive in virtual host (put `#` at the beginning) to make errors will be logged to the main `error_log` file to see what happens.